# How to convert content of html page to single string using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

How to convert content of HTML page to single string using JavaScript?

my HTML page contains labels, text boxes

Thanks in advance........

Comment: What do you exactly mean? The string contains the whole webpage or the information contained in labels, text boxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display like this in script

```
<script>
var content = document.body.innerHTML;
alert (content);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will output to console the whole content of the body tag of your page.

```
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the entire page between and including the `<html>` tags:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML
```